# mupdf on linux segmentation fault

Tags: linux, qt, mupdf

I hava a operation system running Ubuntu 1804x64 installed in VMware ，use Mupdf1.17 and build success，Qt version is 5.9.8 install by command
`sudo apt-get install qt5-default qtcreator`

my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QLabel>


#include "mupdf/fitz.h"
#include "mupdf/pdf.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    char *input = const_cast< char* >("/home/john/work/123.pdf");
    float zoom, rotate;
    int page_number, page_count;
    fz_context *ctx;
    fz_document *doc;
    fz_pixmap *pix;
    fz_matrix ctm;//0

    int x, y;

    page_number=0;
    //100%
    zoom=100;
    //0
    rotate=0;

       //
       ctx = fz_new_context(NULL, NULL, FZ_STORE_UNLIMITED);
           if (!ctx)
           {
               qDebug()<<stderr<<"cannot create mupdf context";
               return;
           }

       //
       fz_try(ctx)
               fz_register_document_handlers(ctx);
       fz_catch(ctx)
       {
           qDebug()<<stderr<<"cannot register document handlers:"<< fz_caught_message(ctx);
           fz_drop_context(ctx);
           return;
       }



       //
       fz_try(ctx)
           doc = fz_open_document(ctx, input);
       fz_catch(ctx)
       {
           qDebug()<<stderr<< "cannot open document:"<< fz_caught_message(ctx);
           fz_drop_context(ctx);
           return;
       }

       //
       fz_try(ctx)
           page_count = fz_count_pages(ctx, doc);
       fz_catch(ctx)
       {
           qDebug()<<stderr<< "cannot count number of pages:"<< fz_caught_message(ctx);
           fz_drop_document(ctx, doc);
           fz_drop_context(ctx);
           return;
       }

        QString str;
        str = str.setNum(page_count);
        ui->textlabel->setText(str);


       if (page_number < 0 || page_number >= page_count)
       {
           qDebug()<<stderr<< "page number out of range: "<< page_number + 1<<"page count:"<<page_count;
           fz_drop_document(ctx, doc);
           fz_drop_context(ctx);
           return;
       }



       //
       ctm=fz_scale(zoom / 100, zoom / 100);
       ctm=fz_pre_rotate(ctm, rotate);



       //pixmap
       fz_try(ctx)
           pix = fz_new_pixmap_from_page_number(ctx, doc, page_number, ctm, fz_device_rgb(ctx), 0);
       fz_catch(ctx)
       {
           qDebug()<<stderr<< "cannot render page: %s\n"<< fz_caught_message(ctx);
           fz_drop_document(ctx, doc);
           fz_drop_context(ctx);
           return;
       }

        //
        //unsigned char *samples = fz_pixmap_samples(ctx, pix);
        unsigned char *samples = pix->samples;
        int width = fz_pixmap_width(ctx, pix);
        int height = fz_pixmap_height(ctx, pix);

        str = str.setNum(width);
        QString wid;
        wid=wid.setNum(width);
        ui->widthlabel->setText("width: "+wid);

        QString hei;
        hei=hei.setNum(height);
        ui->heightlabel->setText("height: "+hei);

        QImage image(samples, width, height,pix->stride,QImage::Format_RGB888);
        QLabel *label=new QLabel;
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

        ui->layout->addWidget(label); // if (!image.save("a.png")) { // return; // } //

        ui->textlabel->setText("Pdf open success");

        fz_drop_pixmap(ctx, pix);
        fz_drop_document(ctx, doc);
        fz_drop_context(ctx);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

occur segmentation fault。the strange thing is  I installed Qt5.14.2.run official install package，and rebuild with Qt5.14 then the program running correct no segmentation fault.

My truly current environment is a Linux system with Arm architecture，no official install package to install qt only installed by command. is that Qt bug?

```
1   do_scavenging_malloc                                                                                                      0x44b5f0       
2   fz_calloc_no_throw                                                                                                        0x44b75e       
3   hb_face_create_for_tables                                                                                                 0x642237       
4   hb_qt_face_get_for_engine(QFontEngine *)                                                                                  0x7ffff76712ea 
5   QFontEngine::harfbuzzFace() const                                                                                         0x7ffff75b9e00 
6   ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff3ca2447 
7   ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff3ca6f3a 
8   ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff3caba57 
9   ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff75d7244 
10  QFontDatabase::findFont(QFontDef const&, int)                                                                             0x7ffff75d7760 
11  QFontDatabase::load(QFontPrivate const *, int)                                                                            0x7ffff75d7e26 
12  QFontPrivate::engineForScript(int) const                                                                                  0x7ffff75ab9ab 
13  QFontMetricsF::leading() const                                                                                            0x7ffff75cd0a1 
14  ??                                                                                                                        0x7ffff775f22f 
15  QPainter::drawText(QRect const&, int, QString const&, QRect *)                                                            0x7ffff7760206 
16  QStyle::drawItemText(QPainter *, QRect const&, int, QPalette const&, bool, QString const&, QPalette::ColorRole) const     0x7ffff7b42774 
17  chameleon::ChameleonStyle::drawControl(QStyle::ControlElement, QStyleOption const *, QPainter *, QWidget const *) const   0x7ffff145260e 
18  chameleon::ChameleonStyle::drawControl(QStyle::ControlElement, QStyleOption const *, QPainter *, QWidget const *) const   0x7ffff1452351 
19  QPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)                                                                                    0x7ffff7c5763e 
20  QWidget::event(QEvent *)                                                                                                  0x7ffff7b134f8
```

![https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VAaI.png][https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VAaI.png]

other find: use Qt5.14 and use Qt5.9 has diffent depands
QT5.14.2

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcdcda8000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/john/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f950c550000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/john/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f950bc36000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/john/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f950b45b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f950b23c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f950aeb3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f950ab15000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f950a8fd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f950a50c000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f950a280000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f950a063000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /home/john/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f9509bca000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /home/john/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f9509812000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /home/john/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f9507e2f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9507c2b000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9507a29000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9507712000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f950f3e6000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f95074e1000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f950722b000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f9506fb9000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f9506c81000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f9506a59000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f9506855000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f950664f000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f950643a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9506232000)
```

QT5.9.8

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc6ddf8000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f95c72f2000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f95c6b89000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f95c643e000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f95c61b2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f95c5f93000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f95c5c0a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f95c586c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f95c5654000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f95c5263000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f95c5031000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f95c4d93000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f95c4b76000)
    libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007f95c46d5000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f95c431d000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x00007f95c410c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f95c3f08000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f95c3bf1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f95c7b39000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f95c39c0000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f95c370a000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f95c3456000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f95c3229000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f95c1680000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f95c140e000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f95c10d6000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f95c0eae000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f95c0caa000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f95c0aa4000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f95c088f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f95c0687000)
```

Comment: Please provide a small working example, not a link to off-site code.

Comment: thinks,has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Given this part of the stack trace:

```
hb_qt_face_get_for_engine(QFontEngine *)
QFontEngine::harfbuzzFace() const
```

What you're likely seeing is a conflict between the version of harfbuzz included in mupdf and the one qt is using. Probably there has been some API change, and qt is calling the version provided by mupdf which has a different API than was expected.

There are many possible solutions. You could build mupdf (and all it's third party dependencies like harfbuzz) into a .so and ensure the harfbuzz symbols aren't visible from outside that .so, which means qt can't see the mupdf version of harfbuzz and hence will call the intended one. Another solution would be to try building mupdf against the system version of harfbuzz instead of the one within mupdf, but if the APIs have changed that will require code changes to mupdf.

Comment: thanks feedback，Solution 2：First i install libharfbuzz by  ``` sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev ```  ,change mupdf cpp files used harfbuzz ,change makefile not build mupdf harfbuzz,    mupdf build static library success,build Qt project again use new library and libharfbuzz,occur new segmentation fault..
```

Comment: 1   ??  0xfffff37c6d68        2   ?? 0xfffff37cb068       3   ??  0xfffff37cc914       4   ??                                                    0xfffff37ce52c          5   QRasterPaintEngine::drawCachedGlyphs(int, unsigned int const *, QFixedPoint const *, QFontEngine *) 0xfffff761b594
6   QRasterPaintEngine::drawTextItem(QPointF const&, QTextItem const&)0xfffff761e698        7   ?? 0xfffff7633808 8   QTextLine::draw(QPainter *, QPointF const&, QTextLayout::FormatRange const *) const  0xfffff74ea584 9   ??